# ARKit and Recording / Replaying Image+Depth with time lapse

Tags: 3d, arkit

I have two questions related to depth data in a cell phone  situation -

1. Is there any common/recommended data format for Image+Depth with time lapse? In the case of iPhone (a leap of faith in the middle of 2020)/iPad with lidars, ARSession is essentially a Image+Depth with time lapse. I would like to know the correct format for this data.
2. In ARKit, I would really like to have the ability to record / replay Image+Depth with time lapse data. It appears that I have all the data from ARFrame. However, I do not believe I have access to initiate ARFrame with the recorded data.

Comment: According to this  document [A Vetro and K Muller 2013](https://www.merl.com/publications/docs/TR2013-138.pdf), this is called 3D video.

Comment: There are 3D video recording that was two channel videos designed for 2 eyes. That is not it.

Comment: There is a [Kinect project](https://github.com/KeckCAVES/Kinect) that does recording. The files contain color file / depth file / audio file in the same directory. I will follow up more.

Comment: In realsense, they could save to .bag file. I am looking into details of that now.

Comment: Any luck? Have you looked into Replaykit for record and replay video?

Comment: @swiftlearneer, I believe it is a different problem. ReplayKit will generate standard 2D video of what happened. I am looking to record images+depth in a time sequence.